# Python - SciPy Kernal Estimation Example - Density >> 1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm currently working through [this SciPy example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html) on Kernal Estimation. In particular, the one labelled "Univariate estimation".   As opposed to creating random data, I am using asset returns.   My 2nd estimation though (and even the simply norm pdf I create to compare to) are showing a density that peaks at 20, which makes no sense...   My code is as follows:

```
x1 = np.array(data['actual'].values)[1:]
xs1 = np.linspace(x1.min()-1,x1.max()+1,len(x1))
std1 = x1.std()
mean1 = x1.mean()

x2 = np.array(data['log_moves'].values)[1:]
xs2 = np.linspace(x2.min()-.01,x2.max()+.01,len(x2))
#xs2 = np.linspace(x2.min()-1,x2.max()+2,len(x2))
std2 = x2.std()
mean2 = x2.mean()

kde1 = stats.gaussian_kde(x1)  # actuals
kde2 = stats.gaussian_kde(x1, bw_method='silverman')

kde3 = stats.gaussian_kde(x2)  # log returns
kde4 = stats.gaussian_kde(x2, bw_method='silverman')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(x1, np.zeros(x1.shape), 'b+', ms=12)  # rug plot
ax1.plot(xs1, kde1(xs1), 'k-', label="Scott's Rule")
ax1.plot(xs1, kde2(xs1), 'b-', label="Silverman's Rule")
ax1.plot(xs1, stats.norm.pdf(xs1,mean1,std1), 'r--', label="Normal PDF")

ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('Density')
ax1.set_title("Absolute (top) and Returns (bottom) distributions")
ax1.legend(loc=1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(x2, np.zeros(x2.shape), 'b+', ms=12)  # rug plot
ax2.plot(xs2, kde3(xs2), 'k-', label="Scott's Rule")
ax2.plot(xs2, kde4(xs2), 'b-', label="Silverman's Rule")
ax2.plot(xs2, stats.norm.pdf(xs2,mean2,std2), 'r--', label="Normal PDF")

ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('Density')

plt.show()
```

My result:
[image: results]

And for reference, the data going in first and 2nd moments:

```
print std1
print mean1
print std2 
print mean2
4.66416718334
0.0561365678347
0.0219996729055
0.00027330546845
```

Further, if I change the 2nd chart to produce a lognormal PDF, I get a flat line (which, if the Y-axis was correctly scaled like the top, I'm sure would show a distribution like I'd expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a kernel density estimate is a probability *density*. While probability can't be larger than 1, a density can.

Given a probability density curve, you can find the probability within a range `(x_1, x_2)` by integrating the probability density in that range. Judging by eye, the integral under both your curves is approximately 1, so the output appears to be correct.

Comment: Ah right - got you.  Thanks for that.  Any sense on how to convert what I have to a more meaningful result? Ie, I want to visually compare if the 2nd subplot is approximately log-normally distributed.

Comment: If you want to visually compare to a log-normal, you could plot the best-fit log-normal distribution over your density estimate. You could also do this quantitatively if you prefer; e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134924/tests-for-lognormal-distribution

Comment: Ah, perfect thanks. I realized that, when I tried to plot a lognormal earlier, that scipy requires some "S" shape parameter.  thanks eh