# Multivariate gaussian probabilities higher than 1 with numpy/scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, gaussian, stat

I am trying to estimate the probability of some samples assuming that they follow a multivariate gaussian distribution. I start by using my data set to estimate the covariance matrix and the mean vector with numpy and then I use scipy to obtain the probability values of some samples.

The problem I am facing is that the probability values that I get are much higher than 1. Here is the code:

```
import string
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

# sample_list contains my samples
x = np.array(sample_list).T
cov = np.cov(x)
mean_vec = np.mean(x, axis=1)
print "Covariance"
print cov
print "Mean"
print mean_vec
print "Determinant"
print np.linalg.det(cov)

rv = multivariate_normal(mean=mean_vec, cov=cov)
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_vec, cov)
print "Random sample"
print x
print "pdf(x)"
print rv.pdf(x)
```

And here is one result example:

```
Covariance
[[ 0.00114548  0.00126964  0.00163885 -0.00097021]
 [ 0.00126964  0.00147635  0.00181914 -0.00051609]
 [ 0.00163885  0.00181914  0.0023556  -0.00165483]
 [-0.00097021 -0.00051609 -0.00165483  0.01451006]]
Mean
[ 0.04382192  0.05937116  0.05526359  0.36803589]
Determinant
1.23897068383e-15
Random sample
[ 0.04897992  0.0540464   0.06269819  0.30528633]
pdf(x)
150525.528322
```

As you can see, the value of the pdf is way high. Am I doing something wrong in the code? Or maybe there is something about the math that I don't understand.

Thank you!

Comment: (Surely this is a duplicate question.)  The PDF is a *density*, not a probability.  It can be larger than 1.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141951/why-does-scipy-norm-pdf-sometimes-give-pdf-1-how-to-correct-it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326443/python-scipy-kernal-estimation-example-density-1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573046/scipy-stats-multivariate-normal-pdf-produce-a-value-outside-of-0-1-unex, etc.

Comment: Yes indeed. A density can be higher than 1. My bad. Sorry and thank you.